# animation in index.html in Angular App

Tags: angular, css-animations

I am trying to animate a fadeout effect in the 'App Loading' screen when Angular loads the app. However, I cannot find a way through. Here is the code:

```
<div class="container">
<my-app>
  <div class="loadingComp">
    <div class="sk-folding-cube">
      <div class="sk-cube1 sk-cube"></div>
      <div class="sk-cube2 sk-cube"></div>
      <div class="sk-cube4 sk-cube"></div>
      <div class="sk-cube3 sk-cube"></div>
    </div>
    <span>App loading, please wait.</span>
  </div>
  </my-app>
```

tried the CSS below, but in vain:

```
my-app:empty + .loadingComp {
  opacity: 1;
}

my-app:not(:empty) + .loadingComp {
 opacity: 0;
 animation: fadeOut 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Even tried with Angular Animations, but not working. Any suggestion ??

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you want to `fadeOut` the 'App Loading...' message or the first component that loads. But I will cover both cases.

To animate the 'App Loading' message before the root component loads, a script needs to be added that can run the animation. I am using jQuery `fadeTo()` functionality ([doc](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/)).

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <base href="." />
    <title>angular playground</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/core-js@2.4.1/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/reflect-metadata@0.1.3/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/systemjs@0.19.31/dist/system.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app')
        .catch(console.error.bind(console));
    </script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <style>
      #animate {
        width: 100%;
        height: 250px;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: red;
      }
    </style>

    <my-app>
        <div id="animate"><h1>App loading, please wait.</h1></div>
    </my-app>

    <script>
      $( "#animate" ).fadeTo( 750 , 0.1, function() {
          // Animation complete.
        });
   </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

To add animation to the component, I have added the `animations` metadata.

app.ts:

```
import {Component, NgModule, Input, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import {
  trigger,
  state,
  style,
  animate,
  transition
} from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div [@flyInOut]="'out'">
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
  animations: [
    trigger('flyInOut', [
      state('out', style({opacity: 0, transform: 'translateX(0)'})),
      transition('void => *', [
        style({
          opacity: 1,
          //transform: 'translateX(-100%)'
        }),
        animate('1s ease-in')
      ]),
      transition('* => void', [
        animate('0.2s 10 ease-out', style({
          opacity: 0,
          transform: 'translateX(100%)'
        }))
      ])
    ])
  ]
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Here's the Plunker [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/PMGdYRGgGd16MnexxfbW?p=preview) for reference. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Nehal for your time. I solved it using jQuery, but a different method. I assigned an 'id' to the 'my-app' selector and used it in jQuery.

I used this:

```
$("body").on('DOMSubtreeModified', "#myApp", function () {
  $('.loadingComp').fadeOut(function () {
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```